Google chrome on Macbook
The Google chrome thumbnail on my MacBook appears with a small padlock in the left hand corner. I haven't been able to update my MacBook since MacOS 12.x.x. i kept running low on storage and when I delete it's just never enough. I found out that my Google chrome was taking up 23GB. I tried to delete it and got a prompt that it's locked. I was able to delete anyway.
I want to know why that lock icon was there and is it normal for Google chrome to occupy that much storage?
